Form set after Future.delayed won't rebuild after subsequent state change of variable
I have a scenario in which I need to show a Form only after a certain Future is completed (In reality, it is after an animation is completed, but I simplified things in the snippet below for reproducibility).
Then, when the form is filled and submitted and the answer provided in the form is correct, I need to change the color of the font of the form (among other things, but I'm simplifying).
I've tried to do that (changing the form font color) by changing the value of a variable _isAnswerCorrect in a setState, which is passed down to a stateless widget NumberInputField, which is a wrapper to a TextFormField. However, the NumberInputField won't rebuild.
I've also tried setting a key (both UniqueKey() and ValueKey(_isAnswerCorrect.toString())) to NumberInputField, since this solution worked for me in another similar scenarios, but neither have worked.
Just copy and paste the code below in the dartpad to see the actual behavior (here it does not work):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isAnswerCorrect = false;

  Widget _questionForm = Container();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _answerIsCorrect() {
    setState(() {
      _isAnswerCorrect = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Show form'),
              onPressed: () {
                Future.delayed(
                  const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  () => setState(
                    () {
                      _questionForm = SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              child: NumberInputField(
                                isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text('Change Color?'),
                              onPressed: _answerIsCorrect,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _questionForm,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAnswerCorrect;

  const NumberInputField({
    super.key,
    required this.isAnswerCorrect,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color fontColor = Colors.blue;

    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
      fontColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '?',
      ),
    );
  }
}



However, I had successfully managed to do that in another form that was not set only after a Future (here it works) (Just copy and paste the code below in the dartpad to see the behavior):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isAnswerCorrect = false;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _answerIsCorrect() {
    setState(() {
      print('setting state');
      _isAnswerCorrect = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: NumberInputField(
                      isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Change Color?'),
                    onPressed: _answerIsCorrect,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAnswerCorrect;

  const NumberInputField({
    super.key,
    required this.isAnswerCorrect,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color fontColor = Colors.blue;

    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
      fontColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '?',
      ),
    );
  }
}



I must be missing something very trivial here. Any ideas of why that might be?

It's because your form is in different context with the current page context, so the setState not rebuilt the NumberInputField stateless widget. In your code you change _questionForm widget inside onPressed function, in this case, the widget that filled to _questionForm is not in the current context state. Correct me if I'm wrong, it's harder for me to explain it than to implement it.
I modified your code to make it works.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isAnswerCorrect = false;

  /// [_isFormShowed] Manage show/hide form, if it's true it will show form,
  /// otherwise the form will not shown.
  bool _isFormShowed = false;

  /* Removed [_questionForm] */
  // Widget _questionForm = Container();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _answerIsCorrect() {
    setState(() {
      _isAnswerCorrect = true;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildForm() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: NumberInputField(
              isAnswerCorrect: _isAnswerCorrect,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Change Color?'),
            onPressed: _answerIsCorrect,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create [form] variable for manage form widget.
    Widget form = Container();

    // if [_isFormShowed] is true then fill [form] with [_buildForm()]
    if (_isFormShowed) form = _buildForm();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Show form'),
              onPressed: () {
                Future.delayed(
                  const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  // Change [_isFormShowed] value
                  () => setState(() => _isFormShowed = !_isFormShowed),
                );
                print('show');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),

            // Change [_questionForm] widget to [form].
            form,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAnswerCorrect;

  const NumberInputField({
    super.key,
    required this.isAnswerCorrect,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color fontColor = Colors.blue;

    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
      fontColor = Colors.black;
    }

    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: fontColor),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '?',
      ),
    );
  }
}

Changes

Add _isFormShowed for managing show/hide form
Remove _questionForm variable
Add _buildForm() to returning the form widget
Add local variable form for identify which Widget will be shown based on _isFormShowed value.
Change "Change Color" button onPressed functio, for changing _isFormShowed value


Thanks! It worked. The "trick" is just to change "where" the variable that holds the form will be assigned. This was done by changing the state of a variable that controls whether the form should be visible or not (_isFormShowed, in your code), so that the variable that holds the form can be assigned in the build method of the widget. However, I really cannot understand why it works. To be honest, I kind of understood your explanation that it has to do with different contexts, but I still have doubts: e.g. inside the onPressed the context is different than that of build method? Thanks!

Hi again! Another thing I found: if you only assign the form variable one time, like in the second code spinet I shared, and does not allow it to be reassigned at each build (setting the state of _isFormShowed to false at buildForm()), the color will not change as expected. In other words, the solution provided only works because the form variable is assigned at each rebuild. So, in this case, it does not work. Do you know why, considering that in the second code snipet I shared it works (even setting form only one time in build?

Hi, thanks for sharing your valuable findings! i can't answer it surely since the second code snippet works well in my device. Maybe you can create a new question and post your findings there? i really interested for this topic, this topic develop my knowledge about context.
